# jQuery Validation -- Not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am building my first ASP.net MVC application (not my first jQuery & jQuery Validation plugin application), and I am having a terrible time performing the client side validation with the validation plugin.  Does anyone know if there is a problem using the plugin with jQuery-1.3.2.min that comes with VS 2008?

My code is as follows:

```
var v = $("#frmAccount").validate({
                rules: {
                    txtAccount: { minLength: 5,required: true  },
                    txtFName: "required",
                    txtLName: "required"
                },
                message: {               
                    txtAccount: {
                        required: "Account Number is required.",
                        minLength: jQuery.format("Account Number must be {0} or more charaters.")
                    },
                    txtFName: "First Name is required.",
                    txtLName: "Last Name is required.",
                }
            }); //validate
    $("#cmd").click(function() {
        if (v.form()) {
            $("#frmAccount").submit(); 
        } 
    });
```

............................
    <form method="post" action="/Home/checkAccount" id="frmAccount">

            <fieldset>

                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <p>

                    <br />

                    <label for="txtAccount">Account Number:</label>

                    <br />

                    <input id="txtAccount" name="txtAccount" type="text" value="" />


                    <br />

                    <label for="txtFName">First Name:</label>

                    <br />

                    <input id="txtFName" name="txtFName" type="text" value="" />


                    <br />

                    <label for="txtLName">Last Name:</label>

                    <br />

                    <input id="txtLName" name="txtLName" type="text" value="" />


                    <br />

                    <label for="txtLName">Email:</label>

                    <br />

                    <input id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" type="text" value="" />


                </p>

                <p>

                    <input type="button" id="cmd" name="cmd" value="Add" />

                </p>

            </fieldset>

    </form>

When I try to submit the blank form, it returns the default "this field is required" next to the account, fname, & lname fields, but if I input any data into the fields I get various results.

I've tried to just perform the basic validate function (not returning the validate object to the v variable), but that produced similar results.

Have I just overlooked something silly here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adrian Grigore, thanks for your quick response.  However, I think that you might have overlooked the code posted above or something.  *Maybe you were too busy trying to plug you own blog or something*.  IDK.

The REAL issues are as follows:

*In the code above "message" should have been "message**s**"
*Also, I made (what I consider) the basic MS programming background mistake...  I camelCased the work minLength, and (of course) in jQuery it should be **minlength**

Adrian, good luck on the blog!

Comment: Additionally (and quite odd), I found this error by running this HTML & javascript in IE7 with the enable script debugging option on and the IE developer toolbar.  I wasted the beginning of the day testing in FF/Firebug.  Right now I completely confused because firebug has saved me soooo many times in the past and IE has failed me when trying to find these kinds of errors......  I just thought I'd pass along that tidbit.

Comment: Well, that's the kind of mistakes you make when hand-coding your validation logic on the client-side. And it's the reason why I prefer not to do it. I'm sorry that you feel I am just trying to push my blog and there are also many other articles on xVal if you don't like mine. But I still genuinely think that you would be better off using a framework like xVal for client-side validation.

Comment: Adrian, In most cases (and in my past), I would have totally agreed, but in this case I just need to check a single value against the model and then pass the other values to a vendor's application.  Additionally, why would we waste our (as developers) bandwidth to validate a few fields when we can pass it off to the client and we have an awesome tool like jQuery and the validate plugin?  While I enjoyed the insight contained within your blog post, I found it to be overkill for the solution I am trying to implement, and in reality, ASP.net MVC is overkill too.  I just wanted to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

jquery.validate does work fine with jquery 1.32. What do you mean by "various results"?

In any case, since you are using ASP.NET MVC, I'd recommend not coding client-side validation by hand. It's much easier, more stable and fully testable if you use xVal and the DataAnnoationModelBinder instead. Have a look at this article on [client-side validation with ASP.NET MVC](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-3-how-to-cover-all-your-client-side-form-validation-needs-without-writing-any-javascript-part1/).

Comment: Various results I have encountered so far:
-Entering just a 2 number account number sometimes is seen as valid and the form is sent to controller to be processed.
-Entering an account number (as above) and submitting does not produce any validation messages, but does not submit the form (invalid)
-Once account number field is deemed invalid, it does not become valid once the min length is met.
-When form field are all valid prior to submission, the form does not submit and produces no messages.
-etc. etc.

This is an asp.net MVC app., but the only field in the model is the account number......